# julia datetime week number for usa

Tags: julia

The week() function in Julia DateTime implementation returns week number of the year using ISO Calendar which means monday is first day of the week.  In the USA Sunday is the first day of week which causes Sundays to have week number of decremented by 1.  Is there a way to specify the first day of the week as Sunday for week() function?

Comment: Julia follows SI/ISO conventions. (But all keywords of the language, all function defined in Base, all documentation, all github content and all discussion occurs in English; so there's that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monday is baked into the code.

It looks like you just have to deal with it.

```
d = DateTime(2017,11,25) # Saturday
w = Dates.issunday(d) ? Dates.week(d) + 1 : Dates.week(d)
# 47

d = DateTime(2017,11,26) # Sunday
w = Dates.issunday(d) ? Dates.week(d) + 1 : Dates.week(d)
# 48
```

---

Julia 0.6.1
See  JuliaDirectory/share/julia/base/dates/accessors.jl line 35

```
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:ISO_week_date#Algorithms
const WEEK_INDEX = (15, 23, 3, 11)
function week(days)
    w = div(abs(days - 1), 7) % 20871
    c, w = divrem((w + (w >= 10435)), 5218)
    w = (w * 28 + WEEK_INDEX[c + 1]) % 1461
    return div(w, 28) + 1
end
```

Comment: Thank you.  Very Helpful